# Android zero-touch enrollment JSON not able to configure wifi

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, device-policy-manager, wso2-iot

I was following guide mentioned here https://developers.google.com/zero-touch/guides/customer/emm#provision to prepare a JSON which then I can scan and enroll device to our MDM provider.

Here is my sample JSON

```
{
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "sample-component-name",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM": "device admin signature",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "http://download/location/that.apk",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_SKIP_ENCRYPTION": false, 
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE": {
    "serverurl": "my-mdm.server.url", 
    "gid": "testGid", 
    "un":"testUn",
    "pw":"testPass"
},
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID": "wifi-ssid",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_PASSWORD": "correct-password",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_PROXY_HOST": "my-wifi.proxy.host.url",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_PROXY_PORT": "9999"
}
```

When I am converting this JSON to QR code and scanning device, it is able to switch wifi, but probably not able to configure Proxy. I am seeing wifi with no internet icon in notification bar. I cannot actually confirm whether proxy is configured or not because device gets stuck at `Downloading the admin app` screen.

However, when I tried with a wifi without proxy and it worked fine with that. Can somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong with proxy?

Device is running Android 7.0 Nougat.

Thanks

Comment: btw, how are you using Nougat with ZTE? Is it a Pixel device?

Comment: No, we use Zebra device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_PROXY_PORT link says that data type is String so I tried to use port number as string.

Changed it to integer and it works now.

Comment: How was the device able to get the config via zerotouch via internet if it can't get and doesn't know the wifi and proxy details?  Or is it just QR?

Comment: Hey @Looka, this was quite a while ago but yeah we put all the information in QR code and scan the code when device starts.